# How to return from an external link with phonegap(Developing with Android Studio)

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio

I am using *Android Studio* to develop my Phonegap App.

I want to give a back link, which will go to my Android phonegap, and the required section of app will open. I am facing some difficulties with this. Its not working at all. Where did I go wrong? Please suggest some fixes. Thank you in advance.

Here in link (the back url to my app) I have given, but here I am not sure of it. Is it proper way or not?

```html
 <div class="inner-area">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="inner">                     
             <div class="welcome_holder login" style="float:left;width:100%;">                        
                <h2>Thank you for purchasing our package.<br/>
                    <a href="file:///android_asset/www/package.html"><< Back To App</a></h2>  
            </div>
        </div>       
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: two (2) questions. Is the external link on the Internet? Are you using *Android Studio* to develop your APK, or are you building the code on a remote server?

Comment: hi @JesseMonroy650 i am using android studio to develop my phonegap app?Here after clicking upon back button,i just want to return to my app.I mean the app will open.Please suggest me.I am stuggling with this.

Comment: Okay. Last chance.  Is the external link on the Internet?

Comment: I corrected your English. I added *Android Studio* - which you are using. I removed *Phonegap Build* - you are not using it. If you can read English, this FAQ may help [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md) Good Luck.